# Console.log vs printing out variable

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

How come when I use console.log to print out a value in the console window for a string it is not in quotes, but when I just output the variable in the console, it prints quotes. Is there any particular reason for this?

```
var test = “hello”; 
test; 
Output : “hello”

Console.log(test); 
Output: hello
```

Comment: yes, console.log is for just outputting text.  But if you type a variable, you get the inspector of such object,.  So yes, there is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Well , see like this.

```js
var test = "hello"; 
test;  // This is object in self and what is it,
       // it is a string in literal 

// Output comes only from debugger , when you input direct.
// test; this line have no output to the console
// Output : "hello" NO

//console.log(test); // console.log already print string (in native/string is output) but also print objects.
// Output: hello YES

console.log( test + " this is the test")

// See output it is a very clear 
// hello this is the test
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior is for strings to be represented along with quotes in the console.

```
a = 'hi';
a
// returns "hi"
```

The **console** api is different and an exception.

*console.log(object [, object, ...])
Displays a message in the console. Pass one or more objects to this method. Each object is evaluated and concatenated into a space-delimited string.*

So it returns a space-delimited, concatenated string. Which means it will always be a string. Since its always a string, we can do away with the quotes. I suppose the console devs let it be that way to make the point that console.log() will always return the same type (string). Adding quotes might imply the possibility that it could return other things, so it seems to be a UX thing for the console.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is dynamically typed which means a variable can store any type of value at any time. If you call a variable storing a string (which is test in your case) it prints out the value "Hello" indicating its a string and returns a string datatype, which is preety straightforward. But numbers can also be strings like var a = "5". On the other hand console.log() simply prints the value inside the variable and by default returns undefined.

```js
var a = "hello";
// To check the return type of variable a which is string
console.log(typeof(a));

// To check the return type of console.log() which is undefined

console.log(typeof(console.log(a)));
```

Comment: It is advisable to include some explanation as well as code.